# Turning off exception logging in HikariPool

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have two databases that are connected to my application and therefore I have two connectors like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = DMP_SAP_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
class SapHanaConnectionConfiguration @Autowired constructor(private val environment: Environment) {

    private val driverClassName by lazy { environment.getProperty(DMP_SAP_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME) }
    private val jdbcString by lazy { environment.getProperty(DMP_SAP_JDBC_STRING) }
    private val username by lazy { environment.getProperty(DMP_SAP_USERNAME) }
    private val password by lazy { environment.getProperty(DMP_SAP_PASSWORD) }

    @Bean(name = [DMP_SAP_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME])
    fun dataSource(): DataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName(driverClassName)
        .url(jdbcString)
        .username(username)
        .password(password)
        .build()

    @Bean(name = [DMP_SAP_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME])
    fun entityManagerFactory(
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier(DMP_SAP_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME) dataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages(DMP_SAP_MODEL_PACKAGE)
        .persistenceUnit(DMP_SAP_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
        .build()

    @Bean(name = [DMP_SAP_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME])
    fun transactionManager(@Qualifier(DMP_SAP_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME) entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory): PlatformTransactionManager =
        JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory)

}
```

Problem is that this particular connector should be working only in production environment, because it connects to the database with clients data (which is located int the inner local network and it is not accessible outside of client's network). Right now while developing in my local environment both connectors start and therefore this `SapHanaConnection` throws exception because it can't establish connection to given DB.

```
2018-10-25 14:04:09.187 ERROR 13680 --- [n(14)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://CLIENTS_MACHINE/ [Unknown host CLIENTS_MACHINE [CLIENTS_MACHINE], -709].
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:126)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB._newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:203)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.newInstance(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:50)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB._connect(DriverSapDB.java:1404)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.DriverSapDB.connect(DriverSapDB.java:1102)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I would like to somehow say that this connector should run only while some profile is active, is it possible?

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin.

Comment: You can add @Profile("production") to the configuration class. that will only run when the profile production is active. Or didn't I understand your question?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible since we can't use spring profiles -> we have to provide already built `war` and we can't influence how is application started (so there can't be --active-profile)